# Maven clean package problems with modules

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project with 4 modules. The main is `GestionCertificados`. It depends of `sgclib`. When I build with the maven command `clean package`, compiler throw me errors that doesn't found that package (but it found other packages from maven central).

What can I do to figure it out this? Is the unique solution to remove the `clean package` command (when I remove it, it works).

[image]

The exact error is:

```
[WARNING] The POM for aa.bb.cc:sgclib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Failed to execute goal on project gestioncertificados: Could not resolve dependencies for project aa.bb.cc:gestioncertificados:war:1.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: aa.bb.cc:sgclib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,  Could not find artifact aa.bb.cc:sgclib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in company
```

(http://nexus.company.cl/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]

The error is like it is searching on my company repository, but I don't need that. The module is local

Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>aa.bb.cc</groupId>
<artifactId>gestioncertificados</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Gestion Certificados</name>

<properties>
    <mainClass>aa.bb.cc.gestioncertificados.tomcat.Server</mainClass>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <jsf-api.version>2.2</jsf-api.version>
    <jsf-mojarra.version>2.2.14</jsf-mojarra.version>
    <primefaces.version>6.1</primefaces.version>
    <primefaces-ext.version>6.0.0</primefaces-ext.version>
    <primefaces-themes.version>1.0.10</primefaces-themes.version>
    <omnifaces.version>2.6.1</omnifaces.version>
    <cdi.version>2.4.2.Final</cdi.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <springsecurity.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <springwebflow.version>2.4.4.RELEASE</springwebflow.version>
    <apache-cxf.version>3.1.5</apache-cxf.version>
    <tomcat.version>8.5.11</tomcat.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>5.3.3.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <hikaricp.version>2.5.1</hikaricp.version>
    <sqlserver.version>6.1.0.jre8</sqlserver.version>
    <jackson.version>2.8.5</jackson.version>
    <javaemailapi.version>1.5.3</javaemailapi.version>
    <poi.version>3.15</poi.version>
    <velocity.version>1.7</velocity.version>
    <velocity-tools.version>2.0</velocity-tools.version>
    <itex.lowagie.version>2.1.7</itex.lowagie.version>
    <flyingsaucer.version>9.1.5</flyingsaucer.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.3.2</commons-lang3.version>
    <commons-collections.version>3.2.1</commons-collections.version>
    <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
    <commons-fileupload.version>1.3.1</commons-fileupload.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
    <commons-beanutils.version>1.8.0</commons-beanutils.version>
    <commons-codec.version>1.4</commons-codec.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <assertj.version>3.2.0</assertj.version>
    <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
    <pdfbox.version>2.0.9</pdfbox.version>
    <woodstox.version>5.1.0</woodstox.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- embed tomcat-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf-mojarra.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF PRIMEFACES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces-ext.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.primefaces</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces-themes.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF OMNIFACES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>${omnifaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CDI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${cdi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- URLREWRITE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
        <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring webflow -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>${springwebflow.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
        <version>${springwebflow.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
        <version>${springwebflow.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>${springwebflow.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Apache POI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-beanutils.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- velocity -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>${velocity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>${velocity-tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- flyingsaucer - xhtmlrenderer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
        <version>${flyingsaucer.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>aa.bb.cc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sgclib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aa.bb.cc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sgclibdocuments</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- war plugin-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>company</id>
        <url>http://nexus.company.cl/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>company</id>
        <url>http://nexus.company.cl/content/groups/public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Could you please provide an excerpt of your POM.xml files (e.g. the parent POM, and one child POM) and the exact error message / stack trace given?

Comment: Hello. Could you please share the error ?

Comment: Assuming among 4 , one is main project and others are modules. Please share pom of main project.

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare your projects that `GestionCertificados` depends on as modules, so you have to install those dependencies to the local maven repository first before you can package `GestionCertificados`.

In your `sgclibdocuments` and `fieldprocessor` call `mvn install`, then your `mvn clean package` should work.

Comment: Is that the unique way? does that means that all my teamworkers have to do the same in theirs environments when they pull the code?

Comment: No, you can use `mvn deploy` as well, which deploys your artifact to your central artifact manager. If you have referenced that in your maven config, maven will also look there.

Comment: Then, what you are saying me is that i can't reference to other module in the same project without creating a repository (local or central).

Comment: I just want to reference it without using a repository

Comment: Then you have to declare your modules in your parent pom, did you do that? (if you think you do please update the question so that we can have a look)

Comment: I have updated it,  i have the dependencies on it. I repeat that when I remove the 'clean package' command all works good, but when I put it, it fails

Comment: Please look in your local maven repository or you companies maven repository if these dependencies are present for the version you specified! If not, install them as specified in my answer. Have you tried that?